# PHP code doesn't save form input in .csv file

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to save some variables in .csv file which is online, but it doesn't work. I tried to create the file by myself and run the code and to let the code creates the file when it runs. But, in both cases it doesn't work

```
<html>
<body>
<?php

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $nationality = $_POST['nationality'];

    if($nationality == "Other")
    $nationality = $_POST['otherNationality'];


    $job = $_POST['job'];
    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $years = $_POST['years'];

    $fh = fopen("results.csv", "a");
    $personalInfo = $name. ", " . $gender . ", " . $nationality . ", " . $job . ", " . $country . ", " .  $years; 

if($fh){
        fwrite($fh, $personalInfo);
        fclose($fh);
    }
```

?>

Comment: It might be permissions issue

Comment: like what? could you clarify please

Comment: check the results.csv is writtable or not

Comment: would you mind to tell me how I can check if it is writable or not?

Comment: Are you using windows or Linux/unix ?

Comment: Linux, but I'm working online (the files are all online)

Comment: Use this php function fileperms ( string $filename )

Comment: it displays this number (33188) ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said it was a permission issue and since you have no access to the CLI you can use the following

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];
$nationality = $_POST['nationality'];

if($nationality == "Other")
$nationality = $_POST['otherNationality'];


$job = $_POST['job'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$years = $_POST['years'];

$opr = chmod ( "results.csv" , 0755 ); 
if($opr)
{
$fh = fopen("results.csv", "a");
$personalInfo = $name. ", " . $gender . ", " . $nationality . ", " . $job . ", " . $country . ", " .  $years; 

 if($fh){
    fwrite($fh, $personalInfo);
    fclose($fh);
}

}
else 
{
     echo "Not able to change the permission :( "; 
}
```

I hope this help

Comment: Not able to change the permission :(

Comment: Do u have FTP or ssh access ?

Comment: I changed using FTP. Thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be anything wrong when it comes to the csv writing - as long a the form fields are initialized.

What you want to make sure is you have permissions to write to that file
_ if this is windows, create the file and give everybody permission to write
_ if this is linux:

```
touch results.csv;  
chmod 777 results.csv
```

Alternatively, try executing it from the commandline php csvscript.php

Comment: If you do not have access to shell, use whatever you are using  to edit files (such as an ftp client or web manager) to set permissions, 777 or give permission to self, group and others to write to the file